# VS Code Remote ssh gives error when connecting to remote (cannot find the public key)

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

VS Code Remote ssh gives error when connecting to remote:

```
> no such identity: publickey.pem: No such file or directory Permission
> denied (publickey).
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid errors when public key is not found - a complete path to the key has to be given:

[image]

The same when using terminal:

[image]